# Will type inference ever work with builders?

Tags: java, type-inference

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488004/generic-type-inference-limits-in-java), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058430/why-doesnt-immutablemap-builder-build-pick-the-correct-type-parameters) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362662/java-type-inference-in-builder-pattern) already show that there are some limits to type inference. I want to give another simple example, and ask if there are known plans to make the compiler smarter, or maybe if newer java versions can already do it (I'm still on Java 8)

Here's my example. It comes up naturally if you try to define "Columns" for some kind of table (`E` is the type of the "row data"):

```java
class Column<E> {

    final String header;
    final Function<E, String> value;
    final int relativeWidth;

    private Column(String header, Function<E, String> value, int relativeWidth) {
        this.header = header;
        this.value = value;
        this.relativeWidth = relativeWidth;
    }

    static <E> Builder<E> create(String header, Function<E, String> value) {
        return new Builder<>(header, value);
    }

    static class Builder<E> {

        private final String header;
        private final Function<E, String> value;
        private int relativeWidth = 1;

        Builder(String header, Function<E, String> value) {
            this.header = header;
            this.value = value;
        }

        Builder<E> width(int relativeWidth) {
            this.relativeWidth = relativeWidth;
            return this;
        }

        Column<E> build() {
            return new Column<>(header, value, relativeWidth);
        }
    }
}
```

Explicitly setting the type parameter is one way to make the compiler understand:

```java
Column<LocalDate> yearColumn = Column.<LocalDate>create("Year",
        d -> Integer.toString(d.getYear()))
        .build();
```

But this does not compile with Java 8:

```java
Column<LocalDate> yearColumn = Column.create("Year",
        d -> Integer.toString(d.getYear()))
        .build();
```

So here are my questions, again:

- What exactly is the name of this limitation?
- Is there a good reason why this shouldn't work?
- Can the compiler infer the type in later Java versions, or are there currently any plans to make it "smarter"?

Comment: That will never work. The compiler can't guess which type it is just based on that it has a `getYear` method. There could be multiple types that has such a method.

Comment: @marstran it could check the type of the variable where the return value is assigned to, but I seem to recall discussion that it's not really worth it since it would involve many cases where it wouldn't work anyway.

Comment: You can also use `Column.<LocalDate>create` rather than specifying the type in the lambda (`(LocalDate d) ->`) if you like

Comment: @marstran The compiler can already do it in a very similar scenario. Try changing the example so that the `create` method returns `Column<E>` directly, rather than `Builder<E>`. Then it won't need an extra hint.

Comment: @Michael thanks, I've updated the example

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something on this;

The function is the limit, it has to return a String. I changed the type of it with `private final Function<E, Object> value;`
Now I can call

```
Column<LocalDate> yearColumn = Column.create("Year",LocalDate::getYear)
    .build();
```

I do not know where you are using the Function.apply method, even it is possible or not to do this, but we can update all value.apply(...) with value.apply(...).toString() if it is necessary.

Here is some example;

```
interface Car {
    enum Shift {AUTO, MANUAL}
    Integer getYear();
    String getModel();
    Long getMileage();

    Shift getShift();

}

public static void main(final String[] args) {


    Column<LocalDate> yearColumn = Column.create("Year",
            LocalDate::getYear)
            .build();

    Column<Car> nameColumn = Column.create("Model",
            Car::getYear)
            .build();

    Column<Car> mileageColumn = Column.create("Mileage",
            Car::getMileage)
            .build();

    Column<Car> shiftColumn = Column.create("Shift",
            Car::getShift)
            .build();

}
```